# Export PreviousCell of PlotGrid to PDF is not working

Tags: graphics, bugs, export, pdf-format

First, run

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{
  {Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True], 
   Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]},
  {Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True], 
   Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]}}]
```

we got

[image]

Then, export previous cell by

```
Export["D:\\1.pdf", NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]]]
```

However, after opening 1.pdf, I only got part of the figure like

[image]

What is wrong? How to export complete previous cell?

**update**
On the other hand, `GraphicsGrid` has no such problem, however, it can not share axis with simple setting.

Comment: This is strange indeed.

Comment: I think it is a bug in `Export`, please report it to the official support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in `Export` (as suspected by @Nasser), which doesn't seem to like the `FontSize->0` setting in the `FrameTicks` of the `PlotGrid` plots. If you did not yet report the issue, please include the following example:

```
ImportString[ExportString[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> FontSize -> 0], "PDF"]]
```

[image]

Knowing this, it's quite easy to work around the issue with `PlotGrid`:

```
Export["D:\\1.pdf", NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]] /. (FontSize -> 0) -> (FontSize -> 0.01)]
```

[image]

As you can see, I simply replace the 0 font size with a tiny (but positive) font size of 0.01.

I'll submit a fixed version for `PlotGrid`, and update this answer as soon as it is accepted.

Comment: Thank you so much for workaround and your wonderful PlotGrid : )

Comment: Thanks for the specific diagnosis.  There seems to be a bug in libcairo, which we use for exporting PDF, SVG, and EPS, where trying to draw with a 0-size font somehow corrupts future drawing.  But it's easy enough for us to work around by simply not allowing 0-size fonts to ever be drawn into cairo in the first place.  That workaround will be in 13.2.

Comment: Hi, Lukas Lang. Somehow this solution does not work anymore. I am using Mathematica 13.2. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @matheorem It appears the fix in 13.2 for the underlying bug broke my workaround... I'll submit a fixed version as soon as I can. In the meantime, you can simply reverse the workaround above, i.e. use `(FontSize -> $MachineEpsilon) -> (FontSize -> 0)` instead of `(FontSize -> 0) -> (FontSize -> 0.01)`

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great : )

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bug in the PDF export itself. Not in the command

```
 Export["D:\\1.pdf", NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]]]
```

To proof this, export to png instead

```
Export["E:/tmp/1.png", NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]]]
```

And now the whole cell shows up.

It seems to affect vector graphics? I tried export to `svg` and it also had same problem as pdf.  But not bitmap graphics as png. Just a theory.

[image]

**Update**

I think the problem could be due to how the graphics from `ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]` is made. Doing the `Grid` manually, the problem goes away (but the grid does not look exactly like the one generated by the resource function ofcourse).

```
r = Grid[{{Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True], 
    Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]}, {Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
     Frame -> True], Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now

```
Export["E:/tmp/1.pdf", NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]]]
```

[image]

So it looks like export to pdf does not like something in how the Graphics is made by this resource function? You might want to report this to the author of this resource function.

Comment: Thank you so much. At least a workaround, though PDF is better, +1

Comment: @matheorem you can convert png image to pdf afterword, but of course the quality will not be as good as if the image was exported to pdf initially.